# Join a table with comma-separated varchar values with another table's Id values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have two tables, let's call them `Users` and `Fruit`.

Users

```
ID   Name    Fruit
-------------------
1    Bob      1,3
2    Jack     3
```

Fruit

```
ID   Name
-------------
 1   Apple
 2   Orange
 3   Grape
```

How does one join those two tables to fill a datatable with the users choice of fruit names?

Would I need to write a stored procedure with a loop?

I am rather new to SQL Server and would be glad for any help or to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: The right direction would be not storing comma separated values, but instead normalizing your database.

Comment: It is Sql Server 2014.

Comment: My company wants me to have it comma seperated like that

Comment: Remove the fruit column from users table. Instead create a third table to store user - fruit.

Comment: If it's a company requirement to store comma separated values, isn't there a colleague who can advise you how its normally done?

Comment: @BryteNyte i added another answer as ur required , maintaining the data as coma separted is bad practice as people suggests .we should follow normalisation for effetctive database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created Physical tables with sample data

```
CREATE TABLE TempUsers 
( ID INT,
  Name  VARCHAR(100),
  Fruit VARCHAR(100)
 )
INSERT INTO TempUsers 
SELECT 1,'Bob' ,'1,3' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Jack','3'

CREATE TABLE TempFruit 
    ( ID INT,
      Name  VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO TempFruit
SELECT 1,'Apple' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Orange'UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Grape'
```

Create A Table-valued-Function to retrive the fruit names as comma separated

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetFruitNames]
(
@vc_String nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS  @OutTable TABLE
(
Reqdata nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE
    (
        DATA nvarchar(max)
    )
    INSERT INTO @Temp
    SELECT @vc_String;

    DECLARE @Temp1 AS TABLE
    (
    DATA nvarchar(max)
    )
    INSERT INTO @Temp1
    SELECT 
            STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+ Name FROM
            (
                SELECT  ID,
                        Name    
                FROm TempFruit 
                WHERE ID IN  ( SELECT    
                                    CAST(Split.a.value('.', 'nvarchar(1000)') AS INT) AS FruitId
                                    FROM
                                    (   SELECT    
                                        CAST( '<S>'+ REPLACE(DATA,',','</S><S>')+'</S>' AS XML) AS FruitId             
                                        FROM @Temp f

                                    )AS A
                                    CROSS APPLY FruitId.nodes('S') AS Split(a))
            ) As dt FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') As FruitName


        INSERT INTO @OutTable
        SELECT * FROM @Temp1
RETURN
END
```

Sql query

```
SELECT ID
      ,Name
      ,uf.Reqdata AS FruitNames
FROM TempUsers u
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[udf_GetFruitNames](u.Fruit) AS uf

Or

SELECT ID
  ,Name
  ,(SELECT Reqdata FROM [dbo].[udf_GetFruitNames](u.Fruit) ) AS FruitNames
  FROM TempUsers u
```

Result

```
ID  Name    FruitNames
---------------------
1   Bob     Apple,Grape
2   Jack    Grape
```

Comment: Thank you very much bud, Really appreciate your help

Comment: @BryteNyte Happy to help bro

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to redesign your tables. There is need for junction table, which will hold which user is connected to what fruit. It is a `N:N` raletionship.

So, you should create such table:

FruitUser

```
UserId  FruitId
1       1
1       3
2       3
```

`UserId` is FK to `Users` table, `FruitId` is FK to `Fruits` table and both of these columns form a compoiste primary key. That's a standard approach.

Then you can use simple join to get results:

```
select * from users u
join FruitUser fu on u.id = fu.userid
join Fruit f on f.id = fu.fruitId
```

Answer (score 1):

For `SQL Server 2014` where you can't use `STRING_SPLIT` , you can split the varchar using `XML` like following.

```
  ;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT id, 
                name, 
                fruitid 
         FROM   (SELECT *, 
                        Cast('<X>' + Replace(F.fruit, ',', '</X><X>') 
                             + '</X>' AS XML) AS xmlfilter 
                 FROM   users F)F1 
                CROSS apply (SELECT fdata.d.value('.', 'varchar(50)') AS FruitId 
                             FROM   f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') AS fdata(d)) O) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte C 
       INNER JOIN fruit F 
               ON F.id = Cast(C.fruitid AS INT)
```

**<kbd>[DEMO](https://rextester.com/BYRXD53231)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

Sample Data

```
DECLARE @Users AS TABLE(ID INt,  Name  VARCHAR(100),fruit VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Users
SELECT 1,'Bob' ,'1,3' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Jack','3'

DECLARE  @Fruit AS TABLE(ID INt,  Name  VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Fruit
SELECT 1,'Apple' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Orange'UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Grape'
```

Sql Script

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT  UserId,
        UserName ,      
        CAST(Split.a.value('.', 'nvarchar(1000)') AS INT) AS FruitId
FROM
(       SELECT  u.ID AS UserId,
                u.Name AS UserName ,      
                CAST( '<S>'+ REPLACE(fruit,',','</S><S>')+'</S>' AS XML) AS FruitId             
        FROM @Fruit f
        INNER JOIN  @Users u
        ON u.ID=f.ID 
)AS A
CROSS APPLY FruitId.nodes('S') AS Split(a)
)
SELECT Userid,
       UserName,
       FruitId,
       ft.name AS FruitName
FROM CTE c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM @Fruit) AS Ft
ON ft.ID=c.FruitId
```

Result

```
Userid  UserName    FruitId   FruitName
------------------------------------------
1        Bob            1       Apple
1        Bob            3       Grape
2        Jack           3       Grape
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift response , is it at all possible to have one userName with selected fruit names comma separated in one column?

Comment: Yes Possible we can write sql script

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desire result without changing anything with this query

```
SELECT u.Id, u.Name, f.name  
FROM Users u
inner join Fruit f  on f.ID IN (SELECT cast(value as int)FROM STRING_SPLIT(u.fruit, ','));
```

Since you have sql server 2014 you have various options like CLR, XML and number functions. Best one is CLR but it's complex. So you can use this XML code.

```
select * from
(SELECT ID, [name],LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS fruitid
    FROM
(SELECT ID,[name],CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(fruit,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x FROM  {User table})t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)) u 
inner join {fruit table} f on f.id = u.fruitid
```